# Regular Expression to get the SRC of images in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a string which contains HTML code and an `image`. I need to get the value of the src attribute from that string. I try to use this code but it's not working

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(wordHTML, "<img.*?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                wordHTML = Regex.Replace(wordHTML, match.Groups[1].Value, "Temp/"+ match.Groups[1].Value);
            }
```

my image path

```
<img width="165" height="138" src="636697542198949135.files/image002.jpg" v:shapes="Рисунок_x0020_7">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julio's answer is a good one, but the next regex uses backreference in case the src has single or double quotes in it and also contemplates empty src's:

```
<img[^>]*?\ssrc=(["'])([^\1]*?)\1
```

The full src of the img (without quotes) will be group number **2** in the regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

`<img\s+[^>]*\bsrc=["']([^"']+)["']`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PMmfdJ/2/)**

```
<img     # literal '<img'
\s+      # one or more 'spaces'
[^>]*    # 0 or more non-'>' character
\b       # word boundary
src=["'] # literal src=
["']     # " or '
([^"']+) # capture: one or more non ' and " character
["']     # literal "
```

Try to specify pattern like this:

```
  string pattern = @"<img\s+[^>]*\bsrc=[\"']([^\"']+)[\"']";

  foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
```

Comment: Could you try to specify the pattern as in the example? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

I am try this expression and this work.

```
src=(?:\"|\')?(?<imgSrc>[^>]*[^/].(?:jpg|bmp|gif|png))(?:\"|\')?
```